# Show Custom Field Product Information on WooCommerce Checkout Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, checkout

I'm trying to display multiple custom product fields on the checkout page. I've found the below code which works for one custom field but how can I add multiple custom fields to it?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_product_field_data', 10, 2 );
function display_custom_product_field_data( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {

    // Define HERE your product custom field meta key  <==   <==   <==   <==   <==
    $meta_key = 'custom_time';

    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $product_id, $meta_key, true );

    if( !empty( $cart_data ) )
        $custom_items = $cart_data;

    if( !empty($meta_value) ) {
        $custom_items[] = array(
            'key'       => __('Time', 'woocommerce'),
            'value'     => $meta_value,
            'display'   => $meta_value,
        );
    }
    return $custom_items;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define $meta_keys as array

```
$meta_keys = array('custom_time','custom_time2'); // or more than tow
```

and other Field

$dictionary = array('custom_time'=>'Time' , 'custom_time2'=>'Date')

```
$product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

foreach($meta_keys as $key=>$meta_key){

$meta_value = get_post_meta( $product_id, $meta_key, true );

if( !empty( $cart_data ) )
    $custom_items = $cart_data;

if( !empty($meta_value) ) {
    $custom_items[] = array(
        'key'       => __( $dictionary[$meta_key] , 'woocommerce'), //or user $meta_key
        'value'     => $meta_value,
        'display'   => $meta_value,
    );
}
}
return $custom_items;
```

Comment: Thanks Ali! This is almost what I'm after. Just with the labels, it displays as **Time0:** and **Time1:**. How can I make the labels custom as well? Example, **Time:** and **Date:**?

Comment: I'm a beginner with php. Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Hi Ali, thank you for that but how can I make the label different to the meta key? So like now the meta key is **custom_time** and I would like the label to be displayed as **Time:**.

Comment: define a dictionary for translate meta_keys to that  want , dictionary  no complicated just define a array 2d , i edited code again for this

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, I just had to add a semicolon at the end of `$dictionary = array('custom_time'=>'Time' , 'custom_time2'=>'Date')`. You're a legend Ali, thank you!